# Swift create custom logic for radio button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have four custom `UIButton`, I applied button image radio (checked and checked). four button I have separate action method I can change the Image easily but if I *checked* first button another three button need *uncheck*. it should react like radio button.

Here, below my code

```
 @IBAction func first_scheme(_ sender: Any) {

        bRec = !bRec
        if (bRec == true) {
            firstscheme_button.setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck.png"), for: .normal)
        } else {

            firstscheme_button.setImage(UIImage(named: "check.png"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

Comment: **Here is working code try it** https://stackoverflow.com/a/51835163/10150796 **another option** https://stackoverflow.com/a/51632267/10150796

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 4 radio buttons at all times, you can put them in an array.

```
var radioButtons: [ButtonType] = [r1, r2, r3, r4]
```

You can now access the button in a loop and set the values for the other button to 'unchecked'.

```
func setRadioButtons(button: ButtonType) {
    for radioButton in radioButtons {
        if radioButton !== button {
            radioButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck.png"), for: .normal)
        }
    }   
}

@IBAction func first_scheme(_ sender: Any) {
    bRec = !bRec
    if bRec {
        firstscheme_button.setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck.png"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        firstscheme_button.setImage(UIImage(named: "check.png"), for: .normal)
    }
    setRadioButtons(button: sender)
}
```

**alternate method**

If all you want to do is *check* the button clicked and *uncheck* the other buttons, the logic is simpler.

Create the **common action** for all radio buttons as well create the **IBOutletcollection** for your all UIButtons ,

```
var radioButtons: [UIButton] = [r1, r2, r3, r4]
```

finally execute the common method as

```
func setRadioButtons(button: UIButton) {
    for getradioButton in radioButtons {
        getradioButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck.png"), for: .normal)
    }
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "check.png"), for: .normal)   
}
```

Comment: @Anbu.karthik i did not write this logic because i did not know what the OP means by `bRec` and the logic behind it.

Comment: are you seen this `but if I checked first button another three button need uncheck`, ?'er is the beginner so she taken the global variable for identify the final click object

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Yea. i'm saying i did not make that assumption because OP is unchecking his button for true? That is all :)

Comment: var radioButtons = [UIButton]()
radioButtons.append(contentsOf: [r1, r2, r3, r4]) update this two lines. Thanks you. Btw How can I get which button is selected within that setRadioButtons function. I mean any values or index like that.

Comment: @Soniya you can edit the answer to better reflect the solution. Btw i think both of them work the same :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you set tags on the buttons with the simple `tag` property, and then you save it from a generic listener.

```
//first button selected
var lastTag = 0
@IBAction func first_scheme(_ sender: UIButton) {
    buttonArray[lastTag].setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck.png"), for: .normal)
    lastTag = sender.tag
    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "check.png"), for: .normal)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can override **isSelected** variable in the custom UIButton and set the image depend on the **isSelected** value.

```
class customButton: UIButton {

    override var isSelected: Bool {

        willSet {

           self.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "checked"), for: .normal)
        }

        didSet {
            self.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "unchecked"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

After making **4** IBOutlets and **4** IBActions for the four custom UIButtons. you can easily select and unselect the buttons and apply your custom behaviour.

```
@IBAction func firstButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

    if let button = sender as? customButton {
        button.isSelected = !button.isSelected
    }

    secondButton.isSelected = false
    thirdButton.isSelected = false
    fourthButton.isSelected = false
}
```